# Is this a correct formula for sin(a b)?

Tags: trigonometry, infinite-product

First of all, recall the complex definitions of the two trigonometric functions:

$$ \sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}, \space \cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}. $$

Now, the formula for $\sin(2x)$ can be derived from these two. But so can it be extended by multipying each new result by $ 2\cos(2^{b}x) $:

$$ 2\sin x \cos x = \sin(2x), \space 4\sin x \cos x \cos(2x) = \sin(4x), \space ...
 $$
and so on. Therefore
$$ 2^{b}\sin x \prod_{n=0}^{b-1}\cos(2^{n}x) = \sin(2^{b}x). $$
However, it might be possible - and this is the step that could be a fallacy - to rewrite the product so as to generalize the outcome to *some* real numbers.
$$ 2^{b}\sin\ x \prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2^{n}x)}{\cos(2^{n}2^{b}x)} = \sin(2^{b}x) =>   \prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2^{n}x)}{\cos(2^{n}bx)} = \frac{\sin(bx)}{b\sin x}.$$

So far, is this true?
Pick x = 1 and notice this is false for b = $\frac{\pi}{4}$. However, for x = 1 and b = $\pi$ or x = 1 and b = 1 the product goes to appropriate values.

Can I now deduce from this the formula for the reciprocal of the product?

$$ \prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2^{n}bx)}{\cos(2^{n}x)} = \frac{b\sin x}{\sin(bx)} $$

Instead of starting the derivation with sinx, I could have started it with $\frac{1}{\sin x}$ and then continued multiplying the denominator. Hence the invalidity of the formula for $\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}, \space n > 1 \space and \space n \in \mathbb{N}, \space$ cannot be explained by the first product's singularities, right?

Is the idea anyhow correct, at least for some numbers?

Comment: If something is false for $b=\pi/4$, then it's false. If it's true for some other values of $b$, that's a coincidence.

Comment: One can still ask for which values of $b$ it does work. $\sum_0^\infty b^{i}= \frac1{1-b}$ fails for $b=2$, but it works for $b=\frac12$, and that is not “a coincidence”.

Comment: There is an error in what you wrote, even for the $2^b$ case, as the term in the product does not converge to $1$, so the product does converge. Perhaps you meant to conjecture: $$ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2^{-n}bx)}{\cos(2^{-n}x)} = \frac{\sin(bx)} {b\sin x}$$
This is true in the case $b=2^k$ with $k\in\mathbb{N}$, by your argument.  More generally the left hand side converges to a well defined function as long as $x$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi$.  Numerically the left and right hand sides give identical functions in $x$, for all random values of $b$ that I tried.

Comment: I could have rewritten the product in your way. Thank you! However, is the derivation rigorous enough to count as a proof? Is the version from the top also correct?

Comment: I have added a proof of my version.  I do not believe your version is correct, or even well defined.  For an infinite product to converge to a non-zero value, a minimal necessary condition is that the terms of the product converge to $1$.  The terms in your product appear to go all over the place!  This is not a proof that your product does not converge, but it seems very unlikely.

Comment: Having plotted it I noticed the possible divergence. The reason that I call it that "possible" is because one can also see the product oscillating near the correct outcome, which might have a meaning.

Comment: To call it oscillation may be wrong. But perhaps the average value of the product after each iteration approaching the correct result is closer to what I intended to say.

Comment: Thanks.  For your product to converge $${\rm min}\left( \left[\left|2^n\frac{x(b-1)}{2\pi}\right|\right], \left[\left|2^n\frac{x(b+1)}{2\pi}\right|\right]\right)\to 0$$   This will only happen when  $\left|\frac{x(b-1)}{2\pi}\right|$ or $\left|\frac{x(b+1)}{2\pi}\right|$ have finite binary expansion.

Comment: Actually, not necessarily finite, but still very specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, I think the conjecture you intended was actually

$$ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2^{-n}bx)}{\cos(2^{-n}x)} = \frac{\sin(bx)} {b\sin x}.$$

This follows immediately from the following identity:

$$ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{\cos(2^{-n}t)} = \frac{\sin t}t,\qquad (1) $$

as we may simply combine the cases $t=bx$ and $t=x$ to get:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2^{-n}bx)}{\cos(2^{-n}x)} &=& 
\frac{\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{\cos(2^{-n}bx)}}{\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{\cos(2^{-n}x)}}\\
\\&=&\frac{\frac{\sin(bx)}{bx}}{\frac{\sin x}x}
\\&=&\frac{\sin(bx)} {b\sin x}
\end{eqnarray*}

The proof of $(1)$  is similar to your original argument:

For $m\in \mathbb{N}$ we have: $$\frac{\sin(2^{-m}t)}{2^{-m}t}\prod_{n=1}^m \cos(2^{-n}t)=\frac{\sin t}t.$$

Letting $m\to \infty$ gives us $(1)$.

This argument seems to have been given many times on this site: see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195825/anybody-know-a-proof-of-prod-n-1-infty-cosx-2n-sin-x-x) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495575/how-to-derive-the-identity-sin-x-x-prod-n-1-infty-cosx-2n-without-usi?rq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3050104/demonstrating-an-equivalent-formula-for-sinx-x-using-power-series?rq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455995/finding-the-limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-cos-frac-x-2-cdot-cos-frac).

I thought the way you arrived at the conjecture was very clever (+1) and reminded me of Euler's construction of the Gamma function as an infinite product.

Comment: Thank you! The explanation is very clear as well.

Answer (score -2):

note that:
$$\sin(2x)=\frac{e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix}}{2i}=\frac{(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})}{2i}=2\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
Try this expansion with your hypothesis and see what you get

Comment: Yes, it works, but since you picked b = 2, your answer does not concern the possible generalization to non-integer values.